# Injection Keystrokes in a /dev/tty

Tags: linux, key, inject, tty

I have a project where I need to simulate Keystrokes in a /dev/tty. Most stuff is working using the TIOCSTI ioctl, even some special keys can be simulated using escape sequences. Now im at a point where i need to simulate more keys, e.g. the Functions keys. Is there a way i can inject those keys to a tty?

Any idea is appreciated.

Greetings.

Comment: You could get better answers on dedicated sites, like http://superuser.com/ :)

Comment: Thank you, posted there.